# Why does python's socket.getfqdn() return localhost.localdomain sometimes?

Tags: python, networking, hosts

I don't quite understand what I'm seeing when I'm using `socket.getfqdn()` on my host. Here's what I'm seeing, then I'll explain it:

```
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]#
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]#
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getfqdn()
'myawesomehost.iscool.ny.domain.com'
>>> socket.gethostname()
'myawesomehost.iscool.ny.domain.com'
>>>
[1]+  Stopped                 python
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]# vim /etc/hosts
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 myawesomehost.iscool.ny.domain.com
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 myawesomehost.iscool.ny.domain.com
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]#
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]#
[root@myawesomehost.iscool ~]# fg
python

>>> socket.getfqdn()
'localhost.localdomain'
>>> socket.gethostname()
'myawesomehost.iscool.ny.domain.com'
>>>
>>>
>>> exit()
```

So when I append my host's fqdn to the end of the `127.0.0.1` entry in `/etc/hosts`, `socket.getfqdn()` starts returning `localhost.localdomain`. However if I remove it, everything works fine and it returns the correct fqdn.

I read the python socket documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn), and it says something about selecting the first value with a period. But then why doesn't it ALWAYS retrn `localhost.localdomain`?

Basically, I think I've narrowed down my problem to this one reproducible step. But I have no idea what's going on under the hood, and I'd really like to.

Answer (score 2):

The docs say:

> Return a fully qualified domain name for name. If name is omitted or empty, it is interpreted *as the local host*.

I'm sure you're aware that a host can have multiple interfaces, and each interface may have its own IP address (or even several), and *that* IP address can resolve to an FQDN.

So, there's *no* universal canonical FQDN for a host, besides localhost. The latter gets returned if it has a named entry (and it should, I think).

Try `.getfqdn()` *for a particular IP*, or consider using [`gethostbyaddr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr) and fishing the right alias from the list it returns.

I also think it has nothing to do with Python specifically; it's how the IP stack works.

Comment: I think I understand.... But why is `localhost.localdomain` getting returned only when the fqdn of the main interface's IP address is appended to the 127.0.0.1 entry in the hosts file? I'm not passing in a value either time, so the "name is omitted or empty" on both runs.